# Add text and image to specific cell of a table in Google Doc using Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-docs, multiple-columns, tablecell

Context: I have a program that creates a photo directory for 6th-12th grade students and leaders/teachers in a google document. For each student, it inserts a picture, and then several separate lines of text (name, phone number, etc.). Before the start of each new grade, text is inserted to label the grade (i.e. 6th grade). When there is a transition to a new grade (i.e. all the 6th graders are in the directory, and it is now starting on 7th graders), a new page is started and another title is added to label the new grade (i.e. 7th grade). I want to make this into a 3 column directory with 4 students in each column on a page. Since google docs does not allow me to make columns directly, I believe I need to make a table with invisible/white borders. I want to make each page a 4 row x 3 column table. Some grades have more than 12 students (one 4x3 table's worth), so I will need to continue onto multiple pages for certain grades. For pages where there are not 12 students, I will need to make the remainder of cells on the page blank or else make a page break so that the new grade starts on a separate page.

Here is the main question: How do I "append" an image and paragraphs to a specific cell in a table? How would I modify my code below so that the student's photo and multiple lines of information are inserted within a table cell, and then a new table cell is started? I tried making a table where I could access each cell as part of an array, and then append an image and paragraphs to a specific cell, but I couldn't figure out how (that faulty code is not included below).

Sorry for the extensive code. Please let me know if you need clarification. Thanks!

```
var sheetID = "x"; //x = link
var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("y"); //y = link
var body = GDoc.getBody(); //google document body

function loadSheet() {
  body.clear(); //deletes previous doc contents so a new photo directory can be made

//** Variables **//
  //load studentSheet
  var StudentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName('Students');
  var studentdata = StudentSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var PreviousGrade = "0"; //initially sets the previous grade to zero so that the first grade created will be different than the previous grade
  //make variables to hold data from StudentSheet
  for (var studentRowNumber = 1; studentRowNumber < studentdata.length; studentRowNumber++) { //studentdata.length determines speed of program execution
    var FirstName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][1];
    var LastName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][2];
    var Gender = studentdata[studentRowNumber][3];
    var School = studentdata[studentRowNumber][4];
    var Grade = studentdata[studentRowNumber][5];
    var Birthday = studentdata[studentRowNumber][6];
    var MemberCellPhone = studentdata[studentRowNumber][7]; //student or leader cell phone
    var MemberEmail = studentdata[studentRowNumber][8];
    var DadFirstName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][9];
    var MomFirstName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][10];
    var DadLastName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][11];
    var MomLastName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][12];
    var DadEmail = studentdata[studentRowNumber][13];
    var MomEmail = studentdata[studentRowNumber][14];
    var DadCellPhone = studentdata[studentRowNumber][15];
    var MomCellPhone = studentdata[studentRowNumber][16];
    var HomePhone = studentdata[studentRowNumber][17];
    var StreetAddress = studentdata[studentRowNumber][18];
    var City = studentdata[studentRowNumber][19];
    var ZipCode = studentdata[studentRowNumber][20];  
    var longpictureID = studentdata[studentRowNumber][21];  

/** determines whether a page break should be inserted for a transition to the next grade **/  
    var CurrentGrade = Grade; 
 if (CurrentGrade !== PreviousGrade) { //new grade category
      if (PreviousGrade !== "0") { //this is not the first grade category
        GDoc.appendPageBreak();
      }
      if (PreviousGrade == "0") { //this is the first grade category
        var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph(""); //blank line inserted before first age category title to make things line up evenly on document with columns; modify as needed
      }
      if (CurrentGrade == "6" || CurrentGrade == "7" || CurrentGrade == "8") { //6-8th; || = or
        var GradeCategory = "MS";
        var GradeCategoryTitle = body.appendParagraph(GradeCategory);
        var NewGradeTitle = body.appendParagraph("Grade " + CurrentGrade);
        var BigBlankLine = body.appendParagraph("");
        var SeparationLine = GDoc.appendParagraph("_________________________");
        PreviousGrade = CurrentGrade;
      }
      if (CurrentGrade == "9" || CurrentGrade == "10" || CurrentGrade == "11" || CurrentGrade == "12") { //9-12th
        var GradeCategory = "HS";
        var GradeCategoryTitle = body.appendParagraph(GradeCategory);
        var NewGradeTitle = body.appendParagraph("Grade " + CurrentGrade);
        var BigBlankLine = body.appendParagraph("");
        var SeparationLine = GDoc.appendParagraph("_________________________");
        PreviousGrade = CurrentGrade;
      }
      if (CurrentGrade == "Leader") {
        var GradeCategory = "Youth";
        var GradeCategoryTitle = body.appendParagraph(GradeCategory);
        var NewGradeTitle = body.appendParagraph("Leaders");
        var BigBlankLine = body.appendParagraph("");
        var SeparationLine = GDoc.appendParagraph("_________________________");
        PreviousGrade = CurrentGrade;
      }     
      GradeCategoryTitle.editAsText().setFontSize(36);
      NewGradeTitle.editAsText().setFontSize(36);
      var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph(""); //blank line
      BigBlankLine.editAsText().setFontSize(36);
      SeparationLine.editAsText().setFontSize(7);
 }      


//** Inserting Picture of Student into Google Doc **//
    //verify if there is a picture uploaded for the student, and if there is then insert it in the google doc
    if (longpictureID !== "") { //there is an uploaded picture
      var shortpictureID = longpictureID.replace('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=', '');
      //(old, new); replace all occurences of old with new in string
    }
      else { //there is not an uploaded picture 
      shortpictureID = "0B5kYlCqpy3BBX2M4M2dWVWEzcjA"; //pic of a silhoutte
      }

      //insert image from drive
         var img = DriveApp.getFileById(shortpictureID).getBlob();
         var inlineI = GDoc.appendImage(img);

         //resizing the image
         var width = inlineI.getWidth();
         var newW = width;
         var height = inlineI.getHeight();
         var newH = height;
         var ratio = width/height;

      //this makes the images all the same height
         newH = 60; 
         newW = parseInt(newH/(1/ratio));
         inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH);

//** insert student info into google doc **//
    var FullName = body.appendParagraph(FirstName + " " + LastName); //combine student's first and last names

    //verify that both parents' names are present
    if (DadFirstName == "" && MomFirstName !== "") { 
        //if dad's name is missing
        var ParentsText = body.appendParagraph("Parents: " + MomFirstName);
    }
      else {
        if (DadFirstName !== "" && MomFirstName == "") { 
        //if mom's name is missing
        var ParentsText = body.appendParagraph("Parents: " + DadFirstName);
        }
        else { 
          if (DadFirstName == "" && MomFirstName == "") {
            //if both parent names are missing
            var ParentsText = body.appendParagraph("Parents: ");
          }
          else {
        //both parent names are given   
        var ParentsText = body.appendParagraph("Parents: " + DadFirstName + " & " + MomFirstName);
        }
       }
      }

    //verify that birthday is given
    if (Birthday !== "") { //birthday is given
      var BirthdayText = body.appendParagraph("Birthday: " + Birthday);
    }
    else { //no birthday is given
      var BirthdayText = body.appendParagraph("Birthday: ");
    }

    //verify that grade is given
    if (Grade !== "") {
      if (Grade == "Leader") { //this is a leader
        var GradeText = body.appendParagraph("Role: " + Grade);
      }
      else { //this is a student
    var GradeText = body.appendParagraph("Grade: " + Grade);
      }
    }
    else { //no grade is given
      var GradeText = body.appendParagraph("Grade: ");
      }

    //determine whether this is a student or leader, and if student then verify that both parents' phone numbers are present
    if (Grade == "Leader" && MemberCellPhone !== "") { //this is a leader and he/she has a cellphone
        var CellTextLabel = body.appendParagraph("Phone: "); //label
        var MemberCellText = body.appendParagraph(MemberCellPhone); //leader's cell phone number
        var DadCellText = "";
        var MomCellText = "";
        //extra blank line is added for email
      }
      else { //this is a student
        if (DadCellPhone == "" && MomCellPhone !== "") { 
           //dad's name is missing
           var CellTextLabel = body.appendParagraph("Phone: ");
           var MomCellText = body.appendParagraph("  Mom - " + MomCellPhone);
           var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph(""); //blank line
           var MemberCellText = "";
           var DadCellText = "";
       }
         else {
           if (DadCellPhone !== "" && MomCellPhone == "") { 
           //mom's name is missing
           var CellTextLabel = body.appendParagraph("Phone: ");
           var DadCellText = body.appendParagraph("  Dad - " + DadCellPhone);
           var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph(""); //blank line
           var MemberCellText = "";
           var MomCellText = "";
           }
           else { 
             if (DadCellPhone == "" && MomCellPhone == "") {
               //both parent names are missing
               var CellTextLabel = body.appendParagraph("Phone: None");
               var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph("");
               var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph("");
               var MemberCellText = "";
               var DadCellText = "";
               var MomCellText = "";
           }
             else {
           //both parent names are given   
           var CellTextLabel = body.appendParagraph("Phone: ");
           var DadCellText = body.appendParagraph("  Dad - " + DadCellPhone);
           var MomCellText = body.appendParagraph("  Mom - " + MomCellPhone);
           var MemberCellText = "";
           }
          }
         }
        }

    //verify that both parents' emails are present
    if (Grade == "Leader" && MemberEmail !== "") { //this is a leader and he/she has an email
        var EmailTextLabel = body.appendParagraph("Email: "); //leader's email
        var MemberEmailText = body.appendParagraph("  " + MemberEmail);
        var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph("");
        var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph(""); //extra blank line for leader email, because there is one less blank line for phone
        var DadEmailText = "";
        var MomEmailText = "";
      }
      else { //this is a student
    if (DadEmail == "" && MomEmail !== "") { 
        //dad's name is missing
        var EmailTextLabel = body.appendParagraph("Email: ");
        var MomEmailText = body.appendParagraph("  Mom - " + MomEmail);
        var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph("");
        var DadEmailText = "";
        var MemberEmailText = "";
    }
      else {
        if (DadEmail !== "" && MomEmail == "") { 
        //mom's name is missing
        var EmailTextLabel = body.appendParagraph("Email: ");
        var DadEmailText = body.appendParagraph("  Dad - " + DadEmail);
        var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph("");
        var MomEmailText = "";
        var MemberEmailText = "";
        }
        else { 
          if (DadEmail == "" && MomEmail == "") {
            //both parent names are missing
            var EmailTextLabel = body.appendParagraph("Email: None");
            var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph("");
            var LittleBlankLine = body.appendParagraph("");
            var DadEmailText = "";
            var MomEmailText = "";
            var MemberEmailText = "";
        }
          else {
        //both parent names are given   
        var EmailTextLabel = body.appendParagraph("Email: ");
        var DadEmailText = body.appendParagraph("  Dad - " + DadEmail);
        var MomEmailText = body.appendParagraph("  Mom - " + MomEmail);
        var MemberEmailText = "";
        }
       }
      }
     }

//** modify text attributes **//
    if (FullName !== "") {
    FullName.editAsText().setBold(false).setFontSize(9).setForegroundColor('#000066'); //black
    }

    if (ParentsText !== "") {
      ParentsText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 8, '#FF0000'); //red
    }

    if (BirthdayText !== "") {
      BirthdayText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 9, '#FF0000');
    }

    if (GradeText !== "") {
      if (Grade == "Leader") { //this is a leader
        GradeText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 5, '#FF0000');
      }
      else { //this is a student
    GradeText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 6, '#FF0000');
      }
    }

    if (CellTextLabel !== "") {
      CellTextLabel.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 6, '#FF0000'); //makes first 6 characters red ("Phone:")
    }
    if (MemberCellText !== "") {
      MemberCellText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066'); //black
    }
    if (DadCellText !== "") {
      DadCellText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066');
    }
    if (MomCellText !== "") {
      MomCellText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066');
    }

    if (EmailTextLabel !== "") {
         EmailTextLabel.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 6, '#FF0000'); //student's email, red
        }
    if (MemberEmailText !== "") {
      MemberEmailText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066'); //black
    }
    if (DadEmailText !== "") {
      DadEmailText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066');
    }
    if (MomEmailText !== "") {
      MomEmailText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066');
    }

    //if (LittleBlankLine !== null) { //not sure if this conditional works
    LittleBlankLine.editAsText().setFontSize(7); 
    //}

    var SeparationLine = GDoc.appendParagraph("_________________________");
    SeparationLine.editAsText().setFontSize(7);
    GDoc.appendParagraph("");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution to my problem, although I'm not sure if it is the most efficient one. Here is the code, in case it is of use to anyone:

```
var sheetID = "x"; //link
var GDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("y"); //link
var body = GDoc.getBody(); //google document body
body.clear(); //deletes previous doc contents so a new photo directory can be made

function loadSheet() { 
var CurrentBoxNumber = 1;
var CurrentBox = 1;
//** Variables **//
  //load studentSheet
  var StudentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID).getSheetByName('Students');
  var studentdata = StudentSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var PreviousGrade = "0"; //initially sets the previous grade to zero so that the first grade created will be different than the previous grade
  //make variables to hold data from StudentSheet
  for (var studentRowNumber = 1; studentRowNumber < studentdata.length; studentRowNumber++) { //studentdata.length determines speed of program execution
    var FirstName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][1];
    var LastName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][2];
    var Gender = studentdata[studentRowNumber][3];
    var School = studentdata[studentRowNumber][4];
    var Grade = studentdata[studentRowNumber][5];
    var Birthday = studentdata[studentRowNumber][6];
    var MemberCellPhone = studentdata[studentRowNumber][7]; //student or leader cell phone
    var MemberEmail = studentdata[studentRowNumber][8];
    var DadFirstName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][9];
    var MomFirstName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][10];
    var DadLastName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][11];
    var MomLastName = studentdata[studentRowNumber][12];
    var DadEmail = studentdata[studentRowNumber][13];
    var MomEmail = studentdata[studentRowNumber][14];
    var DadCellPhone = studentdata[studentRowNumber][15];
    var MomCellPhone = studentdata[studentRowNumber][16];
    var HomePhone = studentdata[studentRowNumber][17];
    var StreetAddress = studentdata[studentRowNumber][18];
    var City = studentdata[studentRowNumber][19];
    var ZipCode = studentdata[studentRowNumber][20];  
    var longpictureID = studentdata[studentRowNumber][21];     

/** determines whether a page break should be inserted for a transition to the next grade **/  
    var CurrentGrade = Grade; 
 if (CurrentGrade !== PreviousGrade) { //new grade category
      if (PreviousGrade !== "0") { //this is not the first grade category
        GDoc.appendPageBreak();
        var table = body.appendTable();
        var Row1 = table.appendTableRow();
        var Row1Cell1 = Row1.appendTableCell();
      }
      if (PreviousGrade == "0") { //this is the first grade category
        var table = body.appendTable();
        var Row1 = table.appendTableRow(); 
        var Row1Cell1 = Row1.appendTableCell();
        //var LittleBlankLine = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph(""); //blank line inserted before first age category title to make things line up evenly on document with columns; modify as needed
        //Row1Cell1
      }
      if (CurrentGrade == "6" || CurrentGrade == "7" || CurrentGrade == "8") { //6-8th; || = or
        var GradeCategory = "MS";
        var GradeCategoryTitle = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph(GradeCategory);
        var NewGradeTitle = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph("Grade " + CurrentGrade);
        var BigBlankLine = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph("");
        //var SeparationLine = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph("_________________________");
        PreviousGrade = CurrentGrade;
        CurrentBoxNumber = 2;
      }
      if (CurrentGrade == "9" || CurrentGrade == "10" || CurrentGrade == "11" || CurrentGrade == "12") { //9-12th
        var GradeCategory = "HS";
        var GradeCategoryTitle = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph(GradeCategory);
        var NewGradeTitle = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph("Grade " + CurrentGrade);
        var BigBlankLine = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph("");
        //var SeparationLine = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph("_________________________");
        PreviousGrade = CurrentGrade;
        CurrentBoxNumber = 2;
      }
      if (CurrentGrade == "Leader") {
        var GradeCategory = "Youth";
        var GradeCategoryTitle = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph(GradeCategory);
        var NewGradeTitle = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph("Leaders");
        var BigBlankLine = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph("");
        //var SeparationLine = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph("_________________________");
        PreviousGrade = CurrentGrade;
        CurrentBoxNumber = 2;
      }     
      GradeCategoryTitle.editAsText().setFontSize(36);
      NewGradeTitle.editAsText().setFontSize(36);
      //var LittleBlankLine = Row1Cell1.appendParagraph(""); //blank line
      BigBlankLine.editAsText().setFontSize(7); //36
      //SeparationLine.editAsText().setFontSize(7);
 }      

 /**   1  5  9
       2  6  10
       3  7  11
       4  8  12
 **/
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 1) {
      var table = body.appendTable();
      var Row1 = table.appendTableRow();
      var Row1Cell1 = Row1.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row1Cell1;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 2) {
      var Row2 = table.appendTableRow();
      var Row2Cell1 = Row2.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row2Cell1;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 3) {
      var Row3 = table.appendTableRow();
      var Row3Cell1 = Row3.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row3Cell1;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 4) {
      var Row4 = table.appendTableRow();
      var Row4Cell1 = Row4.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row4Cell1;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 5) {
      var Row1Cell2 = Row1.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row1Cell2;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 6) {
      var Row2Cell2 = Row2.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row2Cell2;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 7) {
      var Row3Cell2 = Row3.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row3Cell2;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 8) {
      var Row4Cell2 = Row4.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row4Cell2;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 9) {
      var Row1Cell3 = Row1.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row1Cell3;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 10) {
      var Row2Cell3 = Row2.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row2Cell3;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 11) {
      var Row3Cell3 = Row3.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row3Cell3;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }
    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 12) {
      var Row4Cell3 = Row4.appendTableCell();
      var CurrentBox = Row4Cell3;
      Logger.log(CurrentBox);
    }

//** Inserting Picture of Student into Google Doc **//
    //verify if there is a picture uploaded for the student, and if there is then insert it in the google doc
    if (longpictureID !== "") { //there is an uploaded picture
      var shortpictureID = longpictureID.replace('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=', '');
      //(old, new); replace all occurences of old with new in string
    }
      else { //there is not an uploaded picture 
      shortpictureID = "0B5kYlCqpy3BBX2M4M2dWVWEzcjA"; //pic of a silhoutte
      }

      //insert image from drive
         var img = DriveApp.getFileById(shortpictureID).getBlob();
         var inlineI = CurrentBox.appendImage(img);

         //resizing the image
         var width = inlineI.getWidth();
         var newW = width;
         var height = inlineI.getHeight();
         var newH = height;
         var ratio = width/height;

      //this makes the images all the same height
         newH = 60; 
         newW = parseInt(newH/(1/ratio));
         inlineI.setWidth(newW).setHeight(newH);

//** insert student info into google doc **//
    var FullName = CurrentBox.appendParagraph(FirstName + " " + LastName); //combine student's first and last names

    //verify that both parents' names are present
    if (DadFirstName == "" && MomFirstName !== "") { 
        //if dad's name is missing
        var ParentsText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Parents: " + MomFirstName);
    }
      else {
        if (DadFirstName !== "" && MomFirstName == "") { 
        //if mom's name is missing
        var ParentsText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Parents: " + DadFirstName);
        }
        else { 
          if (DadFirstName == "" && MomFirstName == "") {
            //if both parent names are missing
            var ParentsText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Parents: ");
          }
          else {
        //both parent names are given   
        var ParentsText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Parents: " + DadFirstName + " & " + MomFirstName);
        }
       }
      }

    //verify that birthday is given
    if (Birthday !== "") { //birthday is given
      var BirthdayText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Birthday: " + Birthday);
    }
    else { //no birthday is given
      var BirthdayText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Birthday: ");
    }

    //verify that grade is given
    if (Grade !== "") {
      if (Grade == "Leader") { //this is a leader
        var GradeText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Role: " + Grade);
      }
      else { //this is a student
    var GradeText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Grade: " + Grade);
      }
    }
    else { //no grade is given
      var GradeText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Grade: ");
      }

    //determine whether this is a student or leader, and if student then verify that both parents' phone numbers are present
    if (Grade == "Leader" && MemberCellPhone !== "") { //this is a leader and he/she has a cellphone
        var CellTextLabel = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Phone: "); //label
        var MemberCellText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph(MemberCellPhone); //leader's cell phone number
        var DadCellText = "";
        var MomCellText = "";
        //extra blank line is added for email
      }
      else { //this is a student
        if (DadCellPhone == "" && MomCellPhone !== "") { 
           //dad's name is missing
           var CellTextLabel = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Phone: ");
           var MomCellText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("  Mom - " + MomCellPhone);
           var LittleBlankLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph(""); //blank line
           var MemberCellText = "";
           var DadCellText = "";
       }
         else {
           if (DadCellPhone !== "" && MomCellPhone == "") { 
           //mom's name is missing
           var CellTextLabel = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Phone: ");
           var DadCellText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("  Dad - " + DadCellPhone);
           var LittleBlankLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph(""); //blank line
           var MemberCellText = "";
           var MomCellText = "";
           }
           else { 
             if (DadCellPhone == "" && MomCellPhone == "") {
               //both parent names are missing
               var CellTextLabel = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Phone: None");
               var LittleBlankLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("");
               var LittleBlankLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("");
               var MemberCellText = "";
               var DadCellText = "";
               var MomCellText = "";
           }
             else {
           //both parent names are given   
           var CellTextLabel = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Phone: ");
           var DadCellText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("  Dad - " + DadCellPhone);
           var MomCellText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("  Mom - " + MomCellPhone);
           var MemberCellText = "";
           }
          }
         }
        }

    //verify that both parents' emails are present
    if (Grade == "Leader" && MemberEmail !== "") { //this is a leader and he/she has an email
        var EmailTextLabel = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Email: "); //leader's email
        var MemberEmailText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("  " + MemberEmail);
        var LittleBlankLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("");
        var LittleBlankLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph(""); //extra blank line for leader email, because there is one less blank line for phone
        var DadEmailText = "";
        var MomEmailText = "";
      }
      else { //this is a student
    if (DadEmail == "" && MomEmail !== "") { 
        //dad's name is missing
        var EmailTextLabel = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Email: ");
        var MomEmailText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("  Mom - " + MomEmail);
        var LittleBlankLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("");
        var DadEmailText = "";
        var MemberEmailText = "";
    }
      else {
        if (DadEmail !== "" && MomEmail == "") { 
        //mom's name is missing
        var EmailTextLabel = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Email: ");
        var DadEmailText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("  Dad - " + DadEmail);
        var LittleBlankLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("");
        var MomEmailText = "";
        var MemberEmailText = "";
        }
        else { 
          if (DadEmail == "" && MomEmail == "") {
            //both parent names are missing
            var EmailTextLabel = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Email: None");
            var LittleBlankLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("");
            var LittleBlankLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("");
            var DadEmailText = "";
            var MomEmailText = "";
            var MemberEmailText = "";
        }
          else {
        //both parent names are given   
        var EmailTextLabel = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("Email: ");
        var DadEmailText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("  Dad - " + DadEmail);
        var MomEmailText = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("  Mom - " + MomEmail);
        var MemberEmailText = "";
        }
       }
      }
     }

//** modify text attributes **//
    if (FullName !== "") {
    FullName.editAsText().setBold(false).setFontSize(9).setForegroundColor('#000066'); //black
    }

    if (ParentsText !== "") {
      ParentsText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 8, '#FF0000'); //red
    }

    if (BirthdayText !== "") {
      BirthdayText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 9, '#FF0000');
    }

    if (GradeText !== "") {
      if (Grade == "Leader") { //this is a leader
        GradeText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 5, '#FF0000');
      }
      else { //this is a student
    GradeText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 6, '#FF0000');
      }
    }

    if (CellTextLabel !== "") {
      CellTextLabel.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 6, '#FF0000'); //makes first 6 characters red ("Phone:")
    }
    if (MemberCellText !== "") {
      MemberCellText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066'); //black
    }
    if (DadCellText !== "") {
      DadCellText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066');
    }
    if (MomCellText !== "") {
      MomCellText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066');
    }

    if (EmailTextLabel !== "") {
         EmailTextLabel.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor(0, 6, '#FF0000'); //student's email, red
        }
    if (MemberEmailText !== "") {
      MemberEmailText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066'); //black
    }
    if (DadEmailText !== "") {
      DadEmailText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066');
    }
    if (MomEmailText !== "") {
      MomEmailText.editAsText().setFontSize(7).setForegroundColor('#000066');
    }

    //if (LittleBlankLine !== null) { //not sure if this conditional works
    LittleBlankLine.editAsText().setFontSize(7); 
    //}

    //var SeparationLine = CurrentBox.appendParagraph("_________________________");
    //SeparationLine.editAsText().setFontSize(7);
    //CurrentBox.appendParagraph("");
    table.setBorderColor('#FFFFFF').setBorderWidth(0); //white border

    if (CurrentBoxNumber == 12) {
      CurrentBoxNumber = 1;
    }
    else { //less than 12
      CurrentBoxNumber++;
    }

  }
}
```